# Linq to full outer join multiple tables in a Dataset

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 tables in my dataset

table 0 ,1, 2 has id1 , id2 , id3 columns in common respectively

How can I full outer join  them ?

I have seen many questions raised in stack overflow but they  deal with only 2 tables  . How can I achive this wen i have more than 2 tables

Comment: Why do you think joining 3 tables will be so different to joining 2? What have you tried?

Comment: is that work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var rowData =
                        from row1 in dsResults.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                        join row2 in dsResults.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
                            on row1.Field<decimal>("RecordId") equals row2.Field<decimal>("RecordId2")
                        join row3 in dsResults.Tables[2].AsEnumerable()
                            on row1.Field<decimal>("RecordId") equals row3.Field<decimal>("RecordId3")
                        select row1.ItemArray.Concat(row2.ItemArray).Concat(row3.ItemArray).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

like this you can try out

```
var data= (from t1 in db.table1
           join t2 in db.table2 on t1.ID equals t2.ID into t1t2
           from x in t1t2.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join t3 in db.table3 on t1.ID equals t3.ID into t1t3
           from y in t1t3.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new { t1.id,  x.id,  y.id})
```